# Permute the position of a subset of a vector

Tags: r

I want to permute a subset of a vector.

For example, say I have a vector (x) and I select a random subset of the vector (e.g., 40% of its values).

What I want to do is output a new vector (x2) that is identical to (x) except the positions of the values within the random subset are randomly swapped.

For example:

- *x* = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- *random subset* = 1, 4, 5, 8
- *x2* could be = 4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 6, 7, 5, 9, 10

Here's an an example vector (x) and how I'd select the indices of a random subset of 40% of its values. Any help making (x2) would be appreciated!

```
x <- seq(1,10,1)
which(x%in%sample(x)[seq_len(length(x)*0.40)])
```

Comment: `sample(x, size=4)`? or perhaps `sample(x, size=ceiling(0.4 * length(x)))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First draw a `sample` of proportion `p` from the indices, then sample and re-assign elements with that indices.

```
f <- \(x, p=0.4) {
  r <- sample(seq_along(x), length(x)*p)
  x[r] <- sample(x[r])
  `attr<-`(x, 'subs', r)  ## add attribute w/ indices that were sampled
}

set.seed(42)
f(x)
#  [1]  8  2  3  4  1  5  7 10  6  9
# attr(,"subs")
# [1]  1  5 10  8
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- 1:10
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure there is a faster code to do what you are asking, but, a solution would be:

```
x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <-  which(x%in%sample(x)[seq_len(length(x)*0.40)]) # Defined as "y" the vector of the random subset 

# required libraries
library(combinat)

permutation <- permn(y) # permn() function in R generates a list of all permutations of the elements of x. 
# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calculate-combinations-and-permutations-in-r/

permutation_sampled <- sample(permutation,1) # Sample one of the permutations.

x[y] <- permutation_sampled[[1]] # Substitute the selected permutation in x using y as the index of the elements that should be substituted.
```